# Switch controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have 7 different controllers on my page and I want to have a custom controller that can switch to one of the seven controllers based on switch statement. For ex:-

```
//Custom Controller
app.controller('custom_controller', function($http, $scope, $compile) {

$scope.change = function() {
    switch ($scope.data['model']) {
        case 'Telecom':
            $scope.controller = 'Telecom_Controller';
            break;
        case 'Netflix':
            $scope.controller = 'Netflix_Controller';
            break;
        case 'Bank':
            $scope.controller = 'Bank_Controller';
            break;
        case 'Beauty':
            $scope.controller = 'Beauty_Controller';
            break;
        case 'Mutual Funds':
            $scope.controller = 'MF_Controller';
            break;
        case 'Motor Insurance':
            $scope.controller = 'MI_Controller';
            break;
        case 'Job Hunt':
            $scope.controller = 'Job_Controller';
            break;
        default:
            alert("None Selected");
            break;
    }
};
});
```

And then in the 'html' I want to switch accordingly to that controller like:-

```
<div ng-controller={{ controller }}>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: What is the problem then?

Comment: you define controllers as public function, the type of controllers is class and you can't make it as you do in the codes. is better if you use `ngRoute` or `ui-router` and set controller for each state, then you can switch between states instead controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just seems like a vary bad design and from your description there is no indication you need to do something like this.

**What you can do instead:**

- Create components and show/hide the correct one based on your conditions **(preferred option)**
- Use ui-router and show/hide child views based on your conditions
- Use a child controller and show/hide elements with a correct controller based on your conditions

Here is an example of the component structure.

**View**

```
<telecom-component ng-if="data.model === 'Telecom'"></telecom-component>
<netflix-component ng-if="data.model === 'Netflix'"></netflix-component>
<!-- add other components as necessary -->
```